# Exception order when multiple are possible

Tags: exception, testing, interface

If a function has 2 arguments and both produce exceptions, what order would you have them raised in and where would you define it?

This came up when I was writing a test for a function that would take a directory on disk and compress it into a file. For instance:

```
void Compress(string dirPath, string filePath);
```

I haven't written the function yet and I'm putting my tests in place.

The thing is, if the directory path doesn't exist I'd have an exception for a missing directory thrown and if the file had write permissions in the way I'd have an exception thrown to show that. However, what if both paths would cause exceptions? Would I throw the first, the second, another third one, or is it an unknown state? We'd also considered having a single exception to say "Something broke", but the message would be different in each case so doesn't really help.

I've thought of a few ways around it such as always throwing based upon left to right processing of the arguments, or stating "If dirPath is invalid then X is thrown else if filePath is invalid then Y is thrown" and placing that with the interface definition so that whoever implements it should (hopefully) follow this specification.

Just wondering what approach people would take to this problem.

For reference, this is in C# but I don't think this is a language specific problem.

Comment: I think this is mostly preference, but if it were me, I would throw in the order most logical to me. In this case, you want to compress a folder, so you look for that first and if it has a problem, you shouldn't care if there's a problem with the destination file because you won't even get to that.

Comment: @kylep: completely agreed; see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave it unspecified.  Documentation could say:

> Possible exceptions include: X if dirPath is invalid; Y if filePath is invalid.

If there's a unit test where both are invalid, it could pass as long as either of the two exceptions is thrown.

Because really, anything that actually depends on which exception happens when there are multiple exception-worthy problems is not a good idea.

Comment: That's one other option I considered however I have two problems with this approach:
One problem is that our unit test stuff doesn't allow for more than one possible exception (although that is fixable). The other problem is that I feel a bit uncomfortable with code that can return either this or than for the same input. I think I'd prefer that the order was specified.

Comment: Although I'm not completely comfortable with it, this is the one I've gone with after some more discussion with colleagues. We came to this conclusion since we'd not really have total control over the order that the exceptions were thrown necessarily. However, both this and McWafflestix answers have helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When determining exception order, you should determine what the logical order of failure would be.  So in your example, if the directory doesn't exist and the file write permission isn't allowed, it's not unreasonable to expect that your code will first check for the existence of the directory before attempting to create the target file; therefore, that exception should be thrown from the code which will check for the existence of the directory, which will get done first.

Of course, if you have a specific reason for changing the order of the operations (create write file first, then check source directory), that's perfectly fine; the point is, though, either path will throw an exception, which indicates that SOMETHING went wrong with the operation; how the calling code handles it is up to the calling code.  If you want to trap one type of recoverable exception (filenotwritable, for example) and handle that specifically, and then just trap a general exception for everything else, that's fine; your application should define the protocol by which it considers and handles the exceptions of the called code.